# EF6 still generating spatial classes with wrong usages

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, geospatial

I have few entities [tables] with `DbGeography` [geography] columns and one stored procedure that uses `ObjectParameter` and `IObjectContextAdapter`.

Each time I update EDMX model from database, I need to rewrite:

```
//for each geography column
public System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography geoColum
//for class where stored procedure is generated
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Data.Objects.DataClasses;
```

to

```
//for each geography column
public System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography geoColum
//for class where stored procedure is generated
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses;
```

in my project, because it doesn't compile with classes generated by EF.

Why EF 6 still generating this wrong? How can I force EF to generate correct paths?

Answer (score 2):

You're still using code generation from the old version of Entity Framework. Make sure you have correctly updated the project to EF6.

> If you have any models created with the EF Designer, you will need to update the code generation templates to generate EF6 compatible code.
>
> ***Note:** There are currently only EF 6.x DbContext Generator templates available for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013.*
>
> 1. Delete existing code-generation templates. These files will typically be named `<edmx_file_name>.tt` and `<edmx_file_name>.Context.tt` and be nested under your edmx file in Solution Explorer. You can select the templates in Solution Explorer and press the <kbd>Del</kbd> key to delete them.
>
>    ***Note:** In Web Site projects the templates will not be nested under your edmx file, but listed alongside it in Solution Explorer.*
>
>    ***Note:** In VB.NET projects you will need to enable 'Show All Files' to be able to see the nested template files.*
> 2. Add the appropriate EF 6.x code generation template. Open your model in the EF Designer, right-click on the design surface and select **Add Code Generation Item...**
>
>    - If you are using the DbContext API (recommended) then **EF 6.x DbContext Generator** will be available under the **Data** tab.
>
>      ***Note:** If you are using Visual Studio 2012, you will need to install the EF 6 Tools to have this template. See  Get Entity Framework for details.*
>    - If you are using the ObjectContext API then you will need to select the **Online** tab and search for **EF 6.x EntityObject Generator**.
> 3. If you applied any customizations to the code generation templates you will need to re-apply them to the updated templates.

See [Upgrading to EF6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I've started this project with EF 6 so that's why I'm little confused, but I'll try to use this info if it helps, thanks.